# Changing error messages

Tags: registration, error-pages

( v2.7.3 )

Hi, I'm using the Simple Registration addon and allowing the form to use the email address as user and screen name. However, if an email address is not valid it triggers an error for both user and screen name as well as email, which is confusing for the user.

> ·        The username you chose is not available
>   ·        The screen name you chose is not available
>   ·        The email you chose is not available

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by a software update from the addon vendor.